# Name of client lib in mqtt message

Tags: mqtt

As far as I can see, there is no packet field where we can derive from which mqtt client lib (eg paho) and version is used to connect to the mqtt broker, right?

I looked in this document and couln't find anything related: http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no information about the client at all in the message unless you choose to include it in the payload.

Part of the point of MQTT was to make the messages as small as possible. The only information in a message* is the following:

- Topic
- QOS Level
- Retained flag
- Payload

*at least for MQTTv3.x